# Is there a way to obtain IUV map from image in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, uv-mapping

I have been using [detectron2/densepose](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/tree/master/projects/DensePose) to generate IUV map which helped me generate UV texture from the input image. Now, for deployment, I need to have IUV map generation from input image in client-side using JavaScript. I am familiar with TensorFlow but the current dense pose model runs only on PyTorch and interconversion tools are giving errors too.

Any comment or solution to the problem will be very helpful.

IUV image needed:

[image: IUV image]

Final UV map:

[image: UV texture]

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to use `dump` command to generate `pkl` file after that we can generate the needed IUV image.

Inside [Densepose](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/tree/de6416be86155111e05ee102702c55470f7450c6/projects/DensePose) use `apply_net.py` to generate the `pkl` file. It has a lot of other options as well. You can check them out [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/master/projects/DensePose/doc/TOOL_APPLY_NET.md).

`python3 apply_net.py dump configs/densepose_rcnn_R_101_FPN_s1x.yaml /models/R_101_FPN_s1x.pkl /Images/frame.jpg --output output.pkl -v`

After having the `pkl` file we will need to extract information from it and create your IUV needed image.

```py
img = Image.open('/Images/frame.jpg')
img_w ,img_h = img.size
with open('output.pkl','rb') as f:
  data=pickle.load(f)
i = data[0]['pred_densepose'][0].labels.cpu().numpy()
uv = data[0]['pred_densepose'][0].uv.cpu().numpy()
iuv = np.stack((uv[1,:,:], uv[0,:,:], i * 0,))
iuv = np.transpose(iuv, (1,2,0))
iuv_img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(iuv*255),"RGB")
iuv_img.show() #It shows only the croped person

box = data[0]["pred_boxes_XYXY"][0]
box[2]=box[2]-box[0]
box[3]=box[3]-box[1]
x,y,w,h=[int(v) for v in box]
bg=np.zeros((img_h,img_w,3))
bg[y:y+h,x:x+w,:]=iuv
bg_img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(bg*255),"RGB")
bg_img.save('output.png')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
iuv = np.stack((uv[1,:,:], uv[0,:,:], i * 0,))
```

should be

```
iuv = np.stack((uv[1,:,:], uv[0,:,:], i))
```